# Download files from server with WHM

Tags: backup, cpanel, whm

I use a server with WHM. I created monthly backup, it makes full server  backup to /backup folder. I can create targz file with SSH, I know how to download gziped file with pscp, but I don't know how to download it from server with link in browser. I think it's possible, because sysadmin before me did it.
Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to generate a link that you can access through your browser and will be served up by the web server? (your question is a little vague)

These files are stored out of the standard web directories so you could create a symlink in the public_html folder of your website to /backups and call it something obscure so it can't be easily scraped.

So for example public_html/my-secure-backup-folder can be a symlink to /backups.

Guide on creating a symlink here: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9561/29/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-in-cpanel

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to proceed:

Ssh to your WHM server then decide which cpanel account you need to backup. Create a full backup for that cpanel:

```
cd /home/cpaneluser/public_html
/script/pkgacct cpaneluser /home/cpaneluser/public_html
chown cpaneluser:cpaneluser /home/cpaneluser/public_html/cpmove-cpaneluser.tar.gz*
```

Then you can download the backup using your web browser by accessing your cPanel user's domain -> `http://domain.tld/cpmove-cpaneluser.tar.gz`

If you don't know the actual domain for that cPanel user you can do a `cat /etc/userdomains | grep cpaneluser`. It will show the configure domain for that account.

That would be all.

Alternatively you can login to the cPanel account using your web browser -> `http://domain.tld/cpanel` using the user/password combination for that cPanel account. There is a full backup function there (in the cPanel web interface) that does pretty much what I have explained earlier.

Comment: As I said in my question, I use a server with WHM. Not single site under Cpanel.

Comment: As I said in my answer just follow the instructions (updated them)

Comment: Your instruction is for backup account, not full server backup. Do you know, what is difference?

Comment: Being ironic won't help you get the proper answer. Use backup function in WHM and store your backup to a S3 Bucket or create an apache vhost with a symlink to the backup folder as @Brandon advised.